# Enable user to draw a route with mouse on gmap save coordinates

Tags: google-maps, bing-maps

I have a need to develop a site that allows its users to draw/plot a route with the mouse on a Google map. Once this done I need to send the coordinates of the route along with some other form data back to the client.

I have no idea how to achieve this or if any plugins/libraries exist that will make the process simpler. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In typical fashion the next link I looked at after posting my request was this http://googlemapsapi.blogspot.co.uk/2008/05/love-my-maps-use-its-line-and-shape.html which answers my question.